# Is my shower drain flange glued

Tags: bathroom, shower

[image]

My shower drain was leaking on to ceiling below and I thought to replace the shower drain flange and reseal it. Since it was probably put 10 years ago.

I am trying to unscrew the flange but it doesn’t budge. I tried to use the tool to unscrew it but no luck. I do notice there’s purple color so thinking if the flange is actually glued at the bottom. ? Is my assumption or text and it’s glued.

Based on what my internet research has suggested it should be only screwed and not glued.

Comment: It looks like it could be glued in there, not sure thought. The top ring should come outso you can repair it. Unless its a one-piece and whoever put it in glued it all in place. You could try breaking it out carefully if you think you can get a complete replacement drain kit that would fit. This could involve cutting the drain pipe and using an adapter to replace the broken section, or a longer drain extension.

Comment: The circular part is the flange which should be screwed in but for whatever reason they glued it. I looked under and the drain is sitting on top of the plywood so I can’t replace it without taking whole thing apart